# GETリクエストStatus Code:499となるのですが、どういう流れでこの番号が表示されるのでしょうか？

Tags: javascript, ajax, network

**作成中ページが「Status Code:499」**
・エラー発生
・ウイルス対策ソフトリンク先をクリックすると、「理由：フィッシングサイトの URL 」と表示されます

---

**原因を探りたいのですが、Chromeコンソールのネットワークheadersタブより何か分かるでしょうか？**
・499はどこが発行？ ウイルス対策ソフト？
・ウイルス対策ソフトは、どういうタイミングで何を元にこの判断を下しているのでしょうか？

・「Request URL」へ向けて、「Query String Parameters」を付与した「Request Headers」を送る？
・GETリクエスト結果が「Response Headers」となって返ってくる？

・「Response Headers」にのみ「499」が付与されているのですが、リクエストを投げたどこかのタイミングで、(PCの？)ウイルス対策ソフトは通信を横取りしてステータスを付与？

---

**最終的にやりたいこと**
・ウイルス対策ソフトを切らずに、499と表示されないようにしたい
(ウイルス対策ソフトを切れば問題ないのですが…)

---

Comment: 問題となってるセキュリティソフト名も書いた方が解答が付きやすいと思います。

Comment: カスペルスキーインターネットセキュリティ2014 です

Answer (score 2):

http 499 で検索すると
- 499 は web server 側の判定である
- web server がレスポンスを送信する前に web UA が接続を切った時に発生
- なので本来 web UA が 499 を受け取るはずが無い
ということがわかります。

当該ウイルス対策ソフトがどういう実装をしているかはわかりませんが
- ブラックリスト判定に合致するか、ホワイトリスト判定に合致しないか、その他の理由により
- コネクション成立直後にウイルス対策ソフトが socket close している
- が故に web server 的には 499 が発生する (server 側判定であり web UA には見えないはず)
- web UA に対して当該ウイルス対策ソフトが、あたかも web server が 499 を返したように振舞っている
ということのようです。

作成中のページ、ということであれば、暫定的に対策ソフトのホワイトリストに追加してみれば？
運用に入った際に最終的にどうすべきかはそのとき考えるということで。